# Image of a bounded linear operator under an odd continuous function.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

I have the following exercise to solve:

Let $H$ be a complex Hilbert-space and $\mathbf{B}(H)$ denote the set of bounded linear operators $H \to H$.  Let $a, b, x \in \mathbf{B}(H)$ with $x^* = x$ and $ax = xb$ and $xa = bx$.

Let $f : \sigma (x) \to \mathbf{C}$ be an odd continuous function. Then $a f(x) = f(x) b$.

I have no idea whatsoever how to start this exercise. Can anyone give me a hint how to tackle it?

Thanks!

Comment: I see that $x$ is self-adjoint; would I be correct in assuming that $\sigma$ is its spectrum?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: You have $ax =xa $. Use this to show the claim for $f (x)=x^{2n+1} $ (in fact, $f (x) =x^k $ for $k\geq 1$ should be ok). Also, do you know the weierstrass approximation theorem?

Comment: Sorry, the $ax = bx$ was a bad typo. It should be $ax = xb$. I've edited it now.

Comment: Ah yes, I haven't thought about the Weierstrass approximation theorem! I'll try to use that one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Show that this holds when $f$ is a polynomial whose terms are all odd. Next, show that any continuous odd $f$ can be approximated uniformly by such polynomials. Then use the definition of the functional calculus to conclude.

Comment: Alright, I'll try here to work it out: For $f(z) = z^{2n + 1}$ with $n \geq 1$ we have $af(x) = ax^{2n + 1} = x^{2n + 1}b$. Indeed, for $n = 0$, this holds true by assumption. Assume it holds for $n - 1$. Then $ax^{2n + 1} = x^{2n - 1}bx^2 = x^{2n - 1}xax= x^{2n + 1}b$ by our assumptions.

Comment: Now let $f$ be any odd function and $p_n$ a series of odd polynomials converging to $f$ uniformly. Then $\Vert af(x) - f(x)b\Vert = \Vert af(x) - a p_n(x) + p_n(x) b - f(x) b\Vert \leq \Vert af(x) - ap_n(x) \Vert + \Vert f(x)b - p_n(x)b \Vert \leq \Vert a \Vert \cdot \Vert f(x) - p_n(x) \Vert + \Vert b \Vert \cdot \Vert f(x) - p_n(x) \Vert$. But the right hand side will go to zero, as the spectrum of $f(x) - p_n(x)$ is equal to $(f - p_n) (\sigma(x))$, and $(f - p_n)(\alpha) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ for all $z \in \sigma(x)$.